# Visualising JSON data in different format using python libraries

Tags: python, json, graph

I have JSON data(format: JSON objects separated by lines) but to visualize this data with mathplotlib I need to first convert this data into an array of JSON objects(2nd format). Is there any way to draw graphs using JSON data in the first format?

code to draw a graph

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a_file = open("./data.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(a_file)
a_file.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(json_object)

df.plot(x='data_point', y='Add',color='maroon', marker='o')
```

Json data separated by lines(first format)

```
{"data_point": 0,"Add": 2977780}
{"data_point": 1,"Add": 3075680}
{"data_point": 2,"Add": 5979880}
{"data_point": 3,"Add": 1553780}
```

An array of JSON objects(2nd format that is converted from 1st format)

```
[{"data_point": 0,"Add": 2977780},
{"data_point": 1,"Add": 3075680},
{"data_point": 2,"Add": 5979880},
{"data_point": 3,"Add": 1553780}]
```

Comment: `json_object = json.load('['+','.join(a_file.splitlines())+']')`?

Comment: For your information, "format: JSON objects separated by lines" is called simply [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/).